# New Windows 7 update disables Firefox features?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

Now, I cannot push "enter" to go to a URL in firefox.
I have to manually click the button.

I didn't do anything except have my computer update.
After update, this happened.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, just you - Windows 7 is up to date and Firefox is running fine here.

I have not heard of this one before but as always, I suggest to debug this you start by disabling all add ons just incase one of them has disabled this.

Comment: +1. No problems over at my end either. I'm running on RC, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use AVG for anti-virus by any chance?  [This post](http://digitalmutterings.com/blog/2009/3/22/your-enter-key-not-working-in-firefox.html) suggests disabling the AVG extension in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a coinsidence I think. You should try Safe Mode of Firefox. An auto-updated extension may lead it.